# QGIS on MAC cannot be opened because of an error

Tags: qgis, mac

I know this question has been answered before, 3 months ago, but cannot work out how to join that thread.

I have been using Mt Lion with QGIS successfully for some weeks but now get the  'Cannot be opened..' message on attempting to start.  I have reinstalled the GDAL framework Complete but without success.

Any suggestions most welcome!

TW

The core of the error message is:

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4/PROJ
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
  Reason: Incompatible library version: QGIS requires version 8.0.0 or later, but PROJ provides version 7.0.0

Comment: According to error message I think you need to update few libraries.. try to update the version OR reinstall I think it will help you and I am researching on your error message.

Answer (score 3):

I received the exact same error message. And I found that [installing the newest PROJ framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#proj) was the only thing necessary to make QGIS work again. Deinstalling QGIS was **not** necessary.

Comment: The same to newest Kingchaos QGIS 2.8.2.1. This solution worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Proj4 is out of date.  Maybe try a complete uninstall and reinstall from the Kyng Chaos build:

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis